# External scripting is not working in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse.

I created the `index.jsp` as

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<input type="text" id="ut"/>
<span id="user_text_feedback"/>
<p id="paragraph">this is a paragraph</p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/keys.js"/>
```

and `keys.js` file as

```
$('#ut').keyup(function(){
    alert('key down');
    console.log("keyup");
});

$('#paragraph').click(function(){

    $('#paragraph').hide();
});
```

when I internally create the script, this works fine.
But when I create the separate folder and file with `keys.js`
this does not work. There is no error at all 
so I have no Idea why this isn't working.

Comment: Did you check the file requests in your browser? *(F12 => Network => scripts, and maybe you have to reload the page)* In particular, checking the path where it tries to fetch `keys.js`. I guess your relative path doesn't resolve right with your seperate folder. Anyways, you should always use root-relative paths for all your assets. In this case I guess it would be `/js/keys.js` *(starting with a slash, not with dots)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/keys.js"></script>
```

Does tagging it like this make any difference?

Comment: it gives an error with Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at keys.js:2

Comment: @fsdfsd Did you inculde jQuery?

Comment: The good news is the file is being properly referenced now. Where do you reference your jQuery file, if at all? You might be referring to code that needs jQuery set up before your code "loads" jQuery -- so you'll just need to pop the jQuery script tag before the key.js one.